# Android admob quarantined by symantec

Tags: android, admob, symantec, trojan

This morning I came back to my computer with this alert, see the image (the lower window is the properties of one of the entries above):

[image: Antivirus notification]

How do I investigate this? Can i use the hash presented to see if it is a false positive? Has anyone else encountered this?

Worth noting could be that I havn't changed anything about the android frameworks recently.

Comment: I just got the exact same thing, without having made any changes lately. I don't have an answer, but now we're two, at least.

Comment: Another one here, no changes recently either.

Comment: I am also seeing this false positive.

Comment: Same here. I just restored the files for the moment.

Comment: I've just let it remain quarantined for now, if someone verifies it as a false positive then one could report it here https://submit.symantec.com/false_positive/ . .. ofcourse after providing their findings here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Google AdMobs is flagged as a security risk by Symantec because:

> This advertisement library may perform the following actions:
>
> Display advertisements in the host application
>
> Send device location (such as
>   GPS coordinates, cell tower location) to a remote location

For some reason Google Play Services was installed on my machine even though Android Studio SDK Manager did not list it as installed:

[image]